# Write expression in php variable like srting

Tags: php, html

Suggest please .. I want to write expression in php variable... but is dose not work.

It is example..

```
  <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
    <div class="dropdown-item">
       <span data-status="<?php echo $status['id'] ?>" class="dropdown-item__sub<?php echo ($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : '' ?>"><?php echo $status['status'] ?></span>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

I want ...

```
foreach($statuses as $status) {
    $html .= '<div class="dropdown-item">';
    $html .= '<span data-status=' . $status['id'] . ' class=' . 'dropdown-item__sub ' . ($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : ''  . '/>' . $status['status']. '</span>';
    $html .= '</div>';
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: When concatenating, you need to wrap the entire expression in parentheses, not just the condition.

Comment: And for future reference, "does not work" is not a good problem description. You should always describe exactly what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Also if you are using `.=` you must initialise the variable before use like `$html = '';` Outside the loop in your case

Comment: Thanks .. I do not have tag span at final result...

Comment: El_Vanja, show example please.

Comment: The example is in the duplicate.  Closing a duplicate page is not a punishment -- it is a way to educationally resolve a questions without adding unnecessary site bloat to Stack Overflow.